# Error Android Mobile Vision for barcode scanning

Tags: android, google-play-services, barcode-scanner

I am trying to implement the second part of the tutorial in this link:

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/reading-qr-codes-using-the-mobile-vision-api--cms-24680

I am getting the error:

> `BarcodeDetector has private access at..`

[image: ERROR IMAGE HERE]

Any idea why?

```
public class ScanActivity extends Activity {
SurfaceView cameraView;
TextView barCodeInfo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scan);
        cameraView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.camera_view);
        barCodeInfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.code_info);

        BarcodeDetector  barcodeDetector = new BarcodeDetector().Builder(this).setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.QR_CODE)
                .build();
    }
}
```

Comment: call `public` instead of `private`.private variables  are variables that are visible only to the class to which they belong.

Comment: @ IntelliJ Amiya   where to put public? look at the image

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to access BarcodeDetector and its constructor is private BarcodeDetector(). BarcodeDetector uses Builder Pattern.

> "Builder pattern builds a complex object using simple objects and
>   using a step by step approach."
>   http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/builder_pattern.htm

so change to the code below :

```
BarcodeDetector  barcodeDetector = new BarcodeDetector.Builder(this).setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.QR_CODE)
            .build();
```

Comment: where Is the difference..? Look at the code I posted, that's exactly what I wrote..

Comment: new BarcodeDetector().Builder
different
new BarcodeDetector.Builder

Comment: the `()` is the difference hehe

Comment: it did thank you very much! - but i couldn't continue the rest of the tuotiral.. i got lost in all the stages..

Comment: why? what`s the problem you are facing?

Comment: i am getting this error:  FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                                         Process: com.app.barcodescanner, PID: 19767                                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
                                                                                at android.hardware.Camera.<init>(Camera.java:568)
                                                                                at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:405)

Comment: are you trying it in emulator ?